# Import CommmonCrypto library to Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, git, xcodebuild, commoncrypto

I am using CommonCrypto library in my swift class:

```
import CommonCrypto
```

It is working and when I am building my project in Xcode it's ok. I have uploaded my code to repository using git. When I clone this code and try build archive with command:

```
xcodebuild -project PNG.xcodeproj -scheme PNG -sdk iphoneos -configuration AppStoreDistribution archive -archivePath $PWD/build/PNG.xcarchive
```

I get error:

```
....swift:38:8: error: no such module 'CommonCrypto'
```

What's wrong? How can I fix this? Why in my local project it's working and with project clone from repository it's not? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>` to the bridging header and include the `Security.framework` in the project.

Comment: I fix it by removing `import CommonCrypto` but without it I get errors when using enums from CommonCrypto so I must replace them with int values.

Comment: Do not replace the Common Crypto values with int values, cast them to the correct type.